# Okay to use double for == comparison and indexing?

Tags: matlab, loops, octave

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264300/1797098) gire mentioned to better not use `==` when comparing doubles.

When creating a increment variable in a `for` loop using `start:step:stop` notation, it's type will be of *double*. If one wants to use this loop variable for indexing and `==` comparisons, might that cause problems due to floating point precision?!

Should one use integers? If so, is there a way to do so with the `s:s:s` notation?

Here's an example

```
a = rand(1, 5);

for ii = length(a):-1:1
  if (ii == 1)      % Comparing var of type double with ==
    b = 0;          
  else
    b = a(ii);      % Using double for indexing
  end

  ...               % Code

end
```

Comment: I don't think this really applies if your increments are integers themselves. I mean, it could go wrong I guess, but since you're not dealing with any decimal points, I see no reason why your computer won't be able to represent all those numbers accurately and so the comparisons should hold. The problem isn't with the double type per se but rather with the presence of fractions represented in decimal form (with finite precision) might need far more precision (or even infinite precision) to be represented in binary. If you're stepping by `-1` in your loop, I think it's safe to use `==`

Comment: there's an entry in Octave's FAQ, [Why is this floating point computation wrong?](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Why_is_this_floating_point_computation_wrong.3F) that explains everything. And it links to a very good article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: However notice that in that answer Gire did not talk about the loop index. The condition you were checking in that problem was on something that was not guaranteed to be an "integer" (`a` was a result of unspecified calculations) therefore his point was certainly valid in that context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the floating point double specification uses 52 bits to store the mantissa (the part after the decimal point) so you can *exactly* represent any integer in the range

```
-4503599627370496 <= x <= 4503599627370496
```

Note that this is larger than the range of an int32, which can only represent

```
      -2147483648 <= x <= 2147483647
```

If you are just using the double as a loop variable, and only incrementing it in integer steps, and you are not counting above 4,503,599,627,370,496 then you are fine to use a double, and to use `==` to compare doubles.

One reason people suggest for not using doubles is that you can't represent some common decimals exactly, e.g. 0.1 has no exact representation as a double. Therefore if you are working with monetary values, it may be better to separately store the data as an int and remember a scale factor of 10x or 100x or whatever.

It's sometimes bad to directly compare floating point numbers for equality because rounding issues can cause two floats to be not equal, even though the numbers are mathematically equal. This generally happens when the numbers are not exactly representable as floats, or when there is a significant size difference between the numbers, e.g.

```
>> 0.3 - 0.2 == 0.1
ans =
     0
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you're indexing between integer bounds with integer steps (even though the variable class is actually `double`), it is ok to use `==` for comparisons with other integers.
- You can cast the indices, if you really want to be safe.

For example:

```
for ii = int16(length(a):-1:1)
    if (ii == 1)
       b = 0;
    end
end
```